# Fixed Navigation - scroll to stick at top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am trying to get a hidden navigation to display as a user starts to scroll down the page. The navigation will not display as the user scrolls. I am not exactly sure why it will not work. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the JavaScript or HTML. If not I can post the CSS as well but for now this is what I have..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta name="language" content="english">

<!-- Modernizr -->
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery -->
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Foundation -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
<!-- Alert box -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/alertbox.js"></script><!--http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp-->
<!-- News ticker -->
<link href="li-scroller.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js"></script>
<!-- Site style -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/SiteStyle.css" />
</head>
<!-- Cookie / Body container -->
<body onload="checkCookie()">  
<nav id="fixedbar">
    <ul id="fixednav">
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="large-1 columns void">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="large-10 medium-12 small-12 columns siteContent">
<header>
<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns">
<div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns">
<img src="img/logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="Main logo."/>
</div>
<div class="large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns userDash">
<div class="large-9 medium-8 small-12 columns userContainer">
<div id="userName">Sign In or Register
</div>
</div>
<div class="large-3 medium-4 small-12 columns cartContainer">
<img src="img/shoppingBag.svg" alt="Shopping bag icon" class="shoppingBagIcon"/><span> 0 </span><span class="shoppingBagText"> Items in your bag</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns tickerContainer">
<ul id="ticker01"><li><div>*** WELCOME TO NOVANI DESIGNS! **</div></li><li><div>* SIGN UP TODAY AND RECIEVE 25% OFF YOUR ENTIRE PURCHASE! **</div></li>
<li><div>* SPEND OVER $50 AND ENJOY FREE SHIPPING! ***</div></li></ul><script type="text/javaScript" src="js/newsscroll.js"></script>
</div>
<div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns nav">
<div class="large-5 medium-5 small-12 columns">
<nav>
   <ul class="mainNav">
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="large-5 medium-5 small-12 columns">
<input type="text" style="height:1.5em;"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
<footer style="height:100em;">
1
</footer>
</div>
<div class="large-1 columns void">&nbsp;</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- Foundation -->
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <!-- News ticker -->
  <script>$(function(){$("ul#ticker01").liScroll();$("ul#ticker02").liScroll({travelocity: 0.15});});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fixedbar a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }); 
  $(window).on('scroll',function() {
    var scrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(scrolltop >= 215) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeIn(250);
    }

    else if(scrolltop <= 210) {
      $('#fixedbar').fadeOut(250);
    }
  });
});
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to make sure you have set `position: fixed` on `#fixedbar`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I take out the display:none; in the css it shows, and it is fixed. However, the JavaScript I believe is supposed to have it display as the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 0):

delete following lines

```
<nav id="fixedbar">
    <ul id="fixednav">
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Why should @M Cangiano do that, thats the menu that should be displayed while scrolling down? Or explain not that briefly.

Comment: `var $ = jQuery;

   $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
                $('.mainNav').css('display', 'none');

}else{
              $('.mainNav').css('display', 'block');
}`

add this code ur jquery file

Comment: Thank you, for such a fast response but it still will not display.

Comment: what 2 you exactly want, when u scroll down hide main menu right

Comment: No, there is a hidden menu that I would like to display when scrolling down.

Comment: <nav id="fixedbar">
    <ul id="fixednav">
      <li><a href="#">Men</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Women</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kids</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

Comment: #fixedbar  is the navigation that i would like to display when scrolling down. When the page loads it is hidden, as you scroll down it should display.

Comment: var $ = jQuery; $(window).scroll(function () { if($(window).scrollTop() > 20) { $('#fixedbar').css('display', 'block'); }else{ $('.fixedbar').css('display', 'none'); }.   Use jquery like this

Comment: Thank you again, but no nothing still.